# Why does fopen/fgets use both mmap and read system calls to access the data?

Tags: c, linux, file, mmap

I have a small example program which simply `fopen`s a file and uses `fgets` to read it. Using `strace`, I notice that the first call to `fgets` runs a `mmap` system call, and then read system calls are used to actually read the contents of the file. on `fclose`, the file is `munmap`ed. If I instead open read the file with open/read directly, this obviously does not occur. I'm curious as to what is the purpose of this `mmap` is, and what it is accomplishing.

On my Linux 2.6.31 based system, when under heavy virtual memory demand these `mmap`s will sometimes hang for several seconds, and appear to me to be unnecessary.

The example code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   FILE *f;
   if ( NULL == ( f=fopen( "foo.txt","r" )))
   {
     printf ("Fail to open\n");
   }
   char buf[256];
   fgets(buf,256,f);
   fclose(f);
}
```

And here is the relevant strace output when the above code is run:

```
open("foo.txt", O_RDONLY)               = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb8039000
read(3, "foo\nbar\n\n"..., 4096)        = 9
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb8039000, 4096)                = 0
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not the file that is `mmap`'ed - in this case `mmap` is used anonymously (not on a file), probably to allocate memory for the buffer that the consequent reads will use.

`malloc` in fact results in such a call to `mmap`. Similarly, the `munmap` corresponds to a call to `free`.

Comment: Interesting. So from this I gather that all read operations on FILE* don't actually read into the provided buffer, but into an additional allocated buffer on the heap and then copy into my buffer. Also, does malloc always result in a call to mmap? I always thought heap was managed locally in userspace and system calls were only made if more memory needed to be added to the process address space. I also always thought sbrk/brk was used for this, not mmap.

Comment: @bdk: Yes, the file functions from the standard library (not the system calls) do keep their own buffer so that when you call `fgets(buf, 1, f)` continuously in a loop, it doesn't result in hundreds of `read` system calls. `malloc` results in an `mmap` when it doesn't have any more space available in userspace - for example, the first `malloc(8)` may result in an `mmap(4096)`, and consequent `malloc(8)`'s will return pointers to the already allocated area until it is exhausted.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it. Everytime I use strace to try to track something down I end up learning something new.

Answer (score 5):

The `mmap` is not mapping the file; instead it's allocating memory for the stdio `FILE` buffering. Normally `malloc` would not use `mmap` to service such a small allocation, but it seems glibc's stdio implementation is using `mmap` directly to get the buffer. This is probably to ensure it's page-aligned (though `posix_memalign` could achieve the same thing) and/or to make sure closing the file returns the buffer memory to the kernel. I question the usefulness of page-aligning the buffer. Presumably it's for performance, but I can't see any way it would help unless the file offset you're reading from is also page-aligned, and even then it seems like a dubious micro-optimization.

Answer (score 2):

from what i have read memory mapping functions are useful while handling large files. now the definition of large is something i have no idea about. but yes for the large files they are significantly faster as compared to the 'buffered' i/o calls.

in the example that you have posted i think the file is opened by the `open()` function and mmap is used for allocating memory or something else.

from the syntax of mmap function this can be seen clearly:

`void *mmap(void *addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fildes, off_t off);`

the second last parameter takes the file descriptor which should be non-negative.
while in the stack trace it is `-1`

Comment: This is wrong. On POSIX stdio cannot be implemented with `mmap` because of wrong semantics when the file is truncated (it will crash with `SIGBUS` rather than giving an error). The `mmap` OP is asking about is not a map of the file; it's simply an anonymous memory allocation.

Comment: that's what i've said " mmap is used for allocating memory or something else"... i didn't say mmap is used for mmapping 'the' file.

Answer (score 0):

Source code of fopen in glibc shows that mmap can be actually used.

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iofopen.c;h=965d21cd978f3acb25ca23152993d9cac9f120e3;hb=HEAD#l36